# "Destroy" action is not finding queried resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, nested-attributes

Having trouble with the basics of working with nested resources.

I have Users (based on devise), who have many Emailtasks. However, on trying to destroy an emailtask, I get a "document not found error." Manually inspecting the database, there is indeed a user with this user id, who has an emailtask with this id.

Routes:

```
    authenticated :user do
      root :to => 'users#index'
      resources :emailtasks
    end

    devise_scope :user do
      root :to => "devise/registrations#new"
      match '/user/confirmation' => 'confirmations#update', :via => :put, :as => :update_user_confirmation
      resources :emailtasks
    end

    devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations", :confirmations => "confirmations" }
    resources :users do
      get 'invite', :on => :member
      resources :emailtasks
    end
```

(I nested "emailtasks" under each type of user - if this is problematic, open to learning so)

Emailtasks controller. Index works fine, destroy doesn't.

```
  def index 
    @user = current_user
    @emailtasks = @user.emailtasks.all
  end

  def destroy
    @user = current_user
    emailtask = Emailtask.find(params[:id])
    @user.emailtask.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to emailtask_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

Index view:

```
  - @emailtasks.each do |emailtask|
    %tr      
      %td= link_to("Delete emailtask", emailtask_path(emailtask), :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure?" }, :method => :delete, :class => 'btn btn-mini')
```

Upon clicking destroy, here's the error:

```
    Started DELETE "/users/50b44012d4aadb1ea4000005/emailtasks/50b55057d4aadbaeaf000003" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-01 13:14:45 -0500
    Processing by EmailtasksController#destroy as HTML
      Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"znRrduerykwNAh9MrBT/oRZgtSuPzznSsmuGgZm7EDE=", "user_id"=>"50b44012d4aadb1ea4000005", "id"=>"50b55057d4aadbaeaf000003"}
      MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (0.8771ms)
      MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=addtocal_development collection=users selector={"$query"=>{"_id"=>"50b44012d4aadb1ea4000005"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 fields=nil (0.8090ms)
      MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=addtocal_development collection=emailtasks selector={"_id"=>"50b55057d4aadbaeaf000003"} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=0 skip=0 fields=nil (0.3309ms)
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms

    Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound (
    Problem:
      Document(s) not found for class Emailtask with id(s) 50b55057d4aadbaeaf000003.
    Summary:
      When calling Emailtask.find with an id or array of ids, each parameter must match a document in the database or this error will be raised. The search was for the id(s): 50b55057d4aadbaeaf000003 ... (1 total) and the following ids were not found: 50b55057d4aadbaeaf000003.
    Resolution:
      Search for an id that is in the database or set the Mongoid.raise_not_found_error configuration option to false, which will cause a nil to be returned instead of raising this error when searching for a single id, or only the matched documents when searching for multiples.):
```

User model:

```
    class User
      include Mongoid::Document
      extend Rolify
      rolify
      include Mongoid::Timestamps

      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
      # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

      ## Database authenticatable
      field :email,              :type => String, :default => ""
      field :encrypted_password, :type => String, :default => ""

      embeds_many :emailtasks
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :emailtasks
      validates_presence_of :email
      ...
```

Emailtask model:

```
    class Emailtask
        include Mongoid::Document
        include Mongoid::Timestamps # adds automagic fields created_at, updated_at
        ...
        embedded_in :user
```

Thoughts? Thanks!

Update: here's the record from the local mongodb:

```
    { "_id" : ObjectId( "50b44012d4aadb1ea4000005" ),
      "confirmed_at" : Date( 1353990162412 ),
      "created_at" : Date( 1353990162412 ),
      "current_sign_in_at" : Date( 1354143479625 ),
      "current_sign_in_ip" : "127.0.0.1",
      "email" : "theiteg@gmail.com",
      "emailtasks" : [ 
        { "_id" : ObjectId( "50b522f2d4aadbaeaf000001" ),
          "content" : null,
          "name" : null,
          "actuallyfrom" : null,
          "updated_at" : Date( 1354048241990 ),
          "created_at" : Date( 1354048241990 ) }, 
        { "_id" : ObjectId( "50b54fc9d4aadbaeaf000002" ),
          "content" : null,
          "name" : null,
          "actuallyfrom" : null,
          "updated_at" : Date( 1354059721425 ),
          "created_at" : Date( 1354059721425 ) }, 
        { "_id" : ObjectId( "50b55057d4aadbaeaf000003" ),
          "content" : null,
          "name" : null,
          "actuallyfrom" : null,
          "updated_at" : Date( 1354059863314 ),
          "created_at" : Date( 1354059863314 ) },
```

Also - manually editing this local db (change a value, add/destroy a record, etc) creates the expected changes when viewing through the localhost rails app.

the full mongoid.yml:

```
    production:
      sessions:
        default:
          uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>

    development:
      # Configure available database sessions. (required)
      sessions:
        # Defines the default session. (required)
        default:
          # Defines the name of the default database that Mongoid can connect to.
          # (required).
          database: addtocal_development
          # Provides the hosts the default session can connect to. Must be an array
          # of host:port pairs. (required)
          hosts:
            - localhost:27017
          options:
            # Change whether the session persists in safe mode by default.
            # (default: false)
            # safe: false

            # Change the default consistency model to :eventual or :strong.
            # :eventual will send reads to secondaries, :strong sends everything
            # to master. (default: :eventual)
            # consistency: :eventual

            # How many times Moped should attempt to retry an operation after
            # failure. (default: 30)
            # max_retries: 30

            # The time in seconds that Moped should wait before retrying an
            # operation on failure. (default: 1)
            # retry_interval: 1
      # Configure Mongoid specific options. (optional)
      options:
        # Configuration for whether or not to allow access to fields that do
        # not have a field definition on the model. (default: true)
        # allow_dynamic_fields: true

        # Enable the identity map, needed for eager loading. (default: false)
        # identity_map_enabled: false

        # Includes the root model name in json serialization. (default: false)
        # include_root_in_json: false

        # Include the _type field in serializaion. (default: false)
        # include_type_for_serialization: false

        # Preload all models in development, needed when models use
        # inheritance. (default: false)
        # preload_models: false

        # Protect id and type from mass assignment. (default: true)
        # protect_sensitive_fields: true

        # Raise an error when performing a #find and the document is not found.
        # (default: true)
        # raise_not_found_error: true

        # Raise an error when defining a scope with the same name as an
        # existing method. (default: false)
        # scope_overwrite_exception: false

        # Skip the database version check, used when connecting to a db without
        # admin access. (default: false)
        # skip_version_check: false

        # User Active Support's time zone in conversions. (default: true)
        # use_activesupport_time_zone: true

        # Ensure all times are UTC in the app side. (default: false)
        # use_utc: false
    production:
      sessions:
        default:
          database: addtocal
          username: <%= ENV['MONGO_UN'] %>
          password: <%= ENV['MONGO_PW'] %>
          hosts:
            - alex.mongohq.com:10071
          options:
            skip_version_check: true
            safe: true


    test:
      sessions:
        default:
          database: addtocal_test
          hosts:
            - localhost:27017
          options:
            consistency: :strong
            # In the test environment we lower the retries and retry interval to
            # low amounts for fast failures.
            max_retries: 1
            retry_interval: 0
```

Comment: i don't know if this helps, but you're looking for a task by its id, and try to destroy @user.emailtasks (this part is never reached, it shouldn't work anyway because the right way to destroy a collection is to call destroy_all). Anyway, have you checked that you loaded your app in the right environment ? This already happened to me, and it took me hours before i understand i was not connected to the right db... (the app launched in production mode... duh)

Comment: I did check the environment, and it's loading correctly / is not launching in production - would have been nice if this was the issue! Your first point seems like it's on the track of what I'm doing wrong - but the few iterations I've tried have not worked, so I wanted to ask the experts. Not sure which of the basics (model, associations, the controller method and the params its using, the view) I'm setting up incorrectly.

Comment: Perhaps in the index view, it should be user_emailtask_path, in the link to destroy? But making this change alone causes a routing error upon reloading "index". ("No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"emailtasks", :user_id=>#<Emailtask _id: 50b44012d4aadb1ea4000006,...")

Comment: problem is, if you are sure that there _is_ a record with id 50b55057d4aadbaeaf000003 in your db, this is not a rails-related issue - or at least it is a configuration problem. you pass the good id to your action, and all you attempt to do at this point is to find it. So if it _is_ in your db and mongoid doesn't find it, the problem comes from mongoid... Double-check that the record exists, and if not, check your configuration (what does your database.yml look like ?)

Comment: That makes sense. More on that point: added my mongoid.yml, above, and pasted in the records from the db itself. Also mentioned above, when I manually change records in this pasted db query, the changes show up in the web view. Still stumped!